# Is there a way to make TextMate remember its state when switching branches?

Tags: git, version-control, textmate

I'm looking for a plugin or bundle which enables TextMate to bind it's state to the current branch. By state I mean open tabs and open folders in the project drawer.

Here is my scenario:

1. working on branch new-cool-feature, with open tabs file1.rb, file2.rb and folder app/model/a/b/ open in project drawer
2. checkout production branch
3. create new branch urgent-bug-fix
4. at this point, all tabs and open folders should be closed in TextMate, so I can start fresh
5. when I finish my work in urgent-bug-fix and checkout new-cool-feature, TextMate should re-open tabs file1.rb and file2.rb and should reopen folder app/model/a/b in the project drawer

Edit: changed the question to better express what I'm looking for

Comment: Don't you use Cmd+T nagivation? I mean, why all the complexity when you can just navigate to a file in a couple of keystrokes, no matter whether it was already open or not.

Comment: Yes I use it. But I don't like to have a lot of distracting open tabs.